# Is it possible to store a comma separated values in casssandra

Tags: database, cassandra

Is it possible to store comma-separated values in a single column of
        Cassandra?

I have list of long values like

```
[1000,1001,1002,1003,1004.......1110]
```

I want to store and access
them as it is.

Comment: what is the problem? it's just text...

Comment: Depends on how you want to access it? Do you want to access a particular column of the CSVs?

Comment: What do you mean by "access them as it is".? You need to add more details to get any meaningful answer